# What are the restrictions on picking up locomotives?

Tags: ticket-to-ride

If, after drawing one of the five cards from the face up train cards, and after replacing that card, the second card is drawn from the top of the deck and is a locomotive card, is the player allowed to keep that card?

Likewise, if both cards are drawn from the the top of the stack and the second card is a locomotive card, is the player allowed to keep that card?

Comment: @those who rejected the tag: As mentioned in the lead answer, this question applies perfectly well to Ticket to Ride Europe as well.

Answer (score 15):

It varies by which Ticket To Ride game you're playing.

In USA, Europe, and Asia, you may do any of the following on your turn:

- Draw a face-up locomotive
- draw two face-up non-locomotive card
- draw two cards off the deck
- draw one face-up non-locomotive and one card off the deck, in either order.

In Switzerland and Nordic Countries:

- draw two face-up cards
- draw two cards off the deck
- draw one face-up card and one card off the deck, in either order.

The difference has a lot to do with how they are used - the Switzerland and Nordic rules don't allow engines to be used for plain routes, only for tunnels and ferries.

Comment: While there are some differences to the rules, in the scenarios the OP is asking about it doesn't vary (especially since before the edit the title specified North America). In any edition of the game, whether you pick up or draw the first card, if you are eligible to draw a second card and it is a locomotive, you get to keep it. There is no version where if the second card drawn from the stack is a locomotive that you do not get to keep it.

Answer (score 13):

The general rule is that if a card is drawn without looking at it, then it doesn't matter whether it's a locomotive or not - you get to keep it regardless. So the answer to both your scenarios is "yes". In fact, if you're really lucky, it's possible to draw two locomotives from the stack.

When you are considering picking up a visible locomotive (i.e. one present in the five face up cards), then different rules apply. You can only pick a face up locomotive if it is the first and only card you pick up. So if you pick another card, either face up or from the stack, then you cannot pick up a face up locomotive.

Answer (score 5):

Yes - just as if the first card drawn from the top of the (face-down) deck is a locomotive card, the player still gets to draw a second (which may also be a locomotive!).  The key point here is that cards drawn from the deck rather than from the face-up cards are *private*; they're information that you don't have to share with other players, so in particular you don't need to let them know whether you've picked up a locomotive card or not.