# Can you pick up a locomotive if it's revealed as a replacement card?

Tags: ticket-to-ride-europe

In Ticket to Ride: Europe, on your turn you can pick up two cards from the face-down deck, two cards except locomotives from the face-up cards or one from each. When I pick up one card from the face-up deck, it gets replaced right away from the draw pile.

If the replacement card is a locomotive card, can I keep it because if I had picked up two from the face-down deck, it would have been mine?

Comment: Ah, looks like this is a duplicate of http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5824/what-are-the-restrictions-on-picking-up-locomotives

Answer (score 6):

**No**, once a card has been revealed as a locomotive, you have to "spend" two draws to pick it up, which means you can't do so since you've already drawn one of your two cards.

From the [official rules](http://cdn1.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/tt_rules_en.pdf) (PDF), emphasis mine:

> If a Locomotive card is one of the five face-up cards, the player who draws it may only draw one card, instead of two. **If, after having drawn one card the replacement card is a locomotive, the player cannot take it.**