# Does everyone get to see the color of a train card drawn from the pile?

Tags: ticket-to-ride

Does a person drawing a train card from the pile have to show everyone the color of the cards drawn?

Comment: Unless a game's rules specify otherwise, cards moved from one private location (e.g. deck) to another (e.g. hand) are kept private in transit too.

Comment: @those who rejected the tag: As the comments to the lead answer discuss, this question applies perfectly well to Ticket to Ride Europe.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, when you draw a card from the deck it is hidden to the rest of the players. Other players only know what you get when you pick one of the face up cards.

One of the benefits of drawing from the deck is others don’t know what you get but you also don’t have a choice of what you get. Another possible benefit depending on the version is the ability to draw a wild card from the deck and get another draw afterwards.

Comment: The other advantage, of course, is that drawing a locomotive (wild card) doesn't end your turn.

Comment: @ikegami Well that depends on the board  you are playing right? On USA you can only pick 1 train (deck or table), while with nordic you can pick again when you pick a train from deck?

Comment: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5824/what-are-the-restrictions-on-picking-up-locomotives

Comment: @RvdK That rule just says that if you pick a locomotive from the face up cards you cannot afterwards pick a card from the deck. But if you pick a card from the deck and it turns out to be a locomotive you can still draw a second card (since picks from the deck are secret this would make a for a weird rule if otherwise).

Comment: @RvdK Reread the answers to the thread you just linked to: on USA, you can pick two cards from the deck, or two face-up non-loco cards, or a single face-up loco card. Ikegami was wrong, though. Your turn still ends once you've drawn your cards; it's just that you get two from the deck versus one face-up loco.

Comment: @lly, Re "*Ikegami was wrong, though. Your turn still ends once you've drawn your cards*", huh? I didn't say otherwise. I fully agree that drawing two cards face-down ends your turn.

Comment: @lly I don't know that anyone's actually wrong here. I think ikegami was implying that "drawing a locomotive doesn't end your turn *before drawing a second card*," which, of course, is what we're all saying anyway.

Comment: @Lord Farquaad, Re "*is what we're all saying anyway*", That's part of it. RvdK also claimed that your turn ends if you draw a face-down loco, but that isn't true.

Comment: @ikegami Oh, yeah I missed that; you're right.